# Similarity of $P^{-1}AP^{-T}$, $P^{-T}P^{-1}A$, and $AP^{-T}P^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why the matrices $P^{-1}AP^{-T}$, $P^{-T}P^{-1}A$, and $AP^{-T}P^{-1}$ have the same eigenvalues? How can we show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if $B=M^{-1}AM$ for some invertible matrix $M$.

e.g., let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$

$\implies Ax=\lambda x$, where $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$

$\implies AMM^{-1}x=\lambda x$ for an $M$ invertible.

$\implies M^{-1}AMM^{-1}x=\lambda M^{-1}x$

$\implies By=\lambda y$ where $y=M^{-1}x$

$\implies \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of B (and $y$ is an eigenvector of $B$).

Now,

- Let $M=P^{-1}A$, then we have $M^{-1}P^{-1}AP^{-T}M=A^{-1}PP^{-1}AP^{-T}P^{-1}A=P^{-T}P^{-1}A$

  $\implies P^{-1}AP^{-T}$ and $P^{-T}P^{-1}A$ are similar.

  This requires $A$ to be invertible though.
- Instead, let $M=PP^{T}$, then we have, $M^{-1}AP^{-T}P^{-1}M=P^{-T}P^{-1}AP^{-T}P^{-1}PP^{T}=P^{-T}P^{-1}A$

  $\implies AP^{-T} P^{-1}$ and $P^{-T}P^{-1}A$ are similar.
- Also, let $M=P$, then we have $M^{-1}P^{-1}AP^{-T}M=PP^{-1}AP^{-T}P^{-1}=AP^{-T}P^{-1}$

  $\implies P^{-1}AP^{-T}$ and $AP^{-T}P^{-1}$ are similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do we need to have $A$ positive definite as an assumption?

Comment: I don't think so, since we have not used non-negative eigen-value assumption anywhere

Comment: Please let me correct my question. Do we need A to be invertible? It bothers me because it appears in the solution.

Comment: you are right, for the first part of the proof done earlier we need this assumption, but we can prove without invertible assumption too, updated the post, please check